# TeXstudio: collapse \usepackage calls

Tags: texstudio

Using `TeXstudio`'s GUI, I would like to collapse the calls of `\usepackage{}` similar to what can be done for a `\paragraph{}`, a `\section{}` etc. The fact that some code can be collapsed in the GUI is identified with a little arrow pointing downward (if expanded) or to the right (if collapsed) next to the first line of code that can be collapsed (see below).

[image: code that can be collapsed]

I've tried using

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
{ % this allows collapsing in the GUI (1/2)
    \usepackage{color}
} % this allows collapsing in the GUI (2/2)
\begin{document}
    text
\end{document}
```

which allows me to collapse the `\usepackage{}` calls but doesn't compile.

In short: I want code that compiles *and* allows me to collapse the code like show in the picture below (as identified by the gray arrow in line `4`). So far, I can either get the code to compile (not using the `{` `}` around the `\usepackage`) *or* I am able to collapse the calls in the GUI.

[image: working example (does not compile)]

Does anyone have a solution or idea?

Comment: Don't do that. Put the `\usepackage`s in a separate file (say, `mypackages.sty`) and then load them with `\usepackage{mypackages}`.

Comment: This is a great solution to the same issue, thank you!!! Is there any particular reason you'd suggest putting the `\usepackage` calls into a different file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Put

```
%BEGIN_FOLD

%END_FOLD
```

around them. This will allow your code to compile because for tex these are comments, however texstudio understands these comments and allows code folding

[image][image]

Comment: exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!!!