# Collapse '\usepackage's in preambule

Tags: texstudio

I have a dozen of included `\usepackage`s and I'd like to collapse them using curly brackets `{` `}` in TeXstudio, but I'm getting error when I do that.

[image]

`↓`

[image]

Do you know either how to avoid errors, or another method to collaps a chunk of `\usepackage`s in my preambule?

Comment: This may be what you're looking for: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/512190/texstudio-collapse-usepackage-calls

Comment: @Fintan, yes, thanks!

Comment: Usually packages assume that they are not loaded within a group, so doing `{\usepackage{foo}}` may be a problem.

Comment: You are loading lipsum?  Also, loading them inside braces is probably a bad idea, as that would normally make all definitions local instead of global.